# is there is any limit for concurrent connection in ab apache benchmarking?

Tags: apache, benchmarking

currently I am using apache benchmark ab for load testing of my url , I just want to knew is there is any maximum limit for concurrent connection (i.e -c) .

if my OS ulimit and other setting are fine then how many concurrent process i am able to open using ab apache benchmarking .

Answer (score 2):

There is a limit of 20,000 on currency.
The error you get if you enter more than 20,000 is:

ab: Invalid Concurrency [Range 0..20000]